# Get Specific Tile when colliding - Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, get, tile

How can I get the specific tile that is colliding with my object.

I have a collider that walks through the tilemap, I want to identify the specific tile that is being collided with and not the entire tilemap.

[Tilemap Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q5d6.png)

Answer (score 1):

To get a specific tile, you need to query the Tilemap using the Tilemap coordinate system. You can convert from normal world coordinates to Tilemap coordinates with [tilemapReference.WorldToCell(position)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GridLayout.WorldToCell.html). Once you have the tilemap coordinate, you can query for the tile using [tilemapReference.GetTile(tilemapPosition)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.GetTile.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){...}` to check if you are colliding with another object.

Comment: I Wanna get a specific tile, and both colliders are triggers :/

Comment: `void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col){...}`